# How to find the total amount of all created objects?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to find a common sum of all created objects through the class "Hamburger" in order to then find the miscalculation of the average amount of ''hamburgers'  (the sum of all orders divided by their number). Using the "calculatePrice" method, I get the total price of the burger. How to search for a common sum of all burgers, that I could divide by their quantity and get the average cost of all "orders" **Tell me how to correctly find the total price of all created burgers?**

```js
сlass Hamburger {

    constructor(size, ...stuffing) {
        this.size = size;
        this.stuffing = stuffing;
        this.toppingArr = [];
        this.counter = ++Hamburger.counter;
    }

    addTooping(toop) {
        return this.toppingArr.push(toop)
    }

    getTooping() {
        const toppName = this.toppingArr.map(el => el.name);
        return `Toopping: ${toppName}`
    }

    getSize() {
        return `${this.size.name} burger\n`
    }

    getStuffing() {
        const stuffName = this.stuffing.map(el => el.name);
        return `Stuffing: ${stuffName}\n`
    }

    calculatePrice() {
        const stuffingCost = this.stuffing.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
        const toppingCost = this.toppingArr.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
        const allCost = this.size.price + stuffingCost + toppingCost;
        return `Total burger price: ${allCost}`
    }

    calculateCalories() {
        const stuffingKcal = this.stuffing.map(el => el.kcal).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
        const toppingKcal = this.toppingArr.map(el => el.kcal).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
        const allKcal = this.size.kcal + stuffingKcal + toppingKcal;
        return `Total burger calories: ${allKcal}`
    }

}
Hamburger.counter = 0;

Hamburger.small = {
    name: 'small',
    price: 10,
    kcal: 200
}
Hamburger.cheese = {
    name: 'cheese',
    price: 4,
    kcal: 10
}
Hamburger.meet = {
    name: ' meet',
    price: 40,
    kcal: 103
}
Hamburger.mayo = {
    name: 'mayo',
    price: 4,
    kcal: 10
}
Hamburger.oil = {
    name: ' oil',
    price: 1,
    kcal: 2
}


let humb1 = new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese, Hamburger.meet);
console.log(humb1.getSize());
console.log(humb1.getStuffing());
humb1.addTooping(Hamburger.mayo);
humb1.addTooping(Hamburger.oil);
console.log(humb1.getTooping());
console.log(humb1.calculatePrice());
console.log(humb1.calculateCalories());
console.log(humb1);
 let humb2 = new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this right, but do you mean `(humb1.calculatePrice() + humb2.calculatePrice()) / 2` ?

Comment: yes,but  not sum manually 2 objects

Comment: I mean you could write a wrapper function `sumBurgers(...burgers){..}` which loops/counts them. is that something you're looking for?

Comment: I thought to write all the created objects into an array and then find their total cost in an array after that to be divided into "this.counter"

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to automatically automatically transfer newly created objects to this method, for further operations with them

Comment: `var myArray = [];` and then `myArray.push(myBurger);` ? I'll put something together for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add up the sum of multiple `Hamburger` elements you have quite a few options. Based on your comment I think you're looking for something like this:

```
let burgers = [];

// create all burgers
burgers.push(new Hamburger(..));
burgers.push(new Hamburger(..));
burgers.push(new Hamburger(..));
burgers.push(new Hamburger(..));

// sum
let sum = burgers.reduce((a,b) => a.calculatePrice() + b.calculatePrice(), 0);

// average
let avg = sum / Hamburger.counter;
```